# Compare strings in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, compare, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary formatted from a plist:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Contents</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>date</key>
                <string>20110323</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>update.zip</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://intranet.webaddress.com/mobile/ipad/</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>date</key>
                <string>20120323</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>plns.galleryy.zip</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://intranet.webaddress.com/mobile/ipad/</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I need to loop though the NSDictionary and grab any name values that have a date string greater than one I supply. So pseudo code (although working) would be like this:

```
NSMutableArray *urls = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

NSMutableDictionary *capabilities;
capabilities = [[myData libraryDictionary] valueForKey:@"Contents"];

for (int i=0; i<[myData libraryCount]; i++) {
    NSString *value = [[capabilities valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([value compare: @"20120323"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        NSLog(@"Equal");
        NSLog(@"%@",value);
        NSString *saveValue = [[capabilities valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:i];
        [urls addObject:saveValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",saveValue);
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Equal");
    }
}
```

Then I would only be downloading the files that have a date that was ahead of the date I supplied. In this simple example I would only add plns.galleryy.zip to my mutable array.

Can anyone help me with this issue? The above works but it is the best way?

note: [myData libraryDictionary] is my dictionary and is reading in fine for other purposes.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a NSDate from your date string:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [NSDateFormatter new];
[format setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD"];

foreach (NSString *dateStr in dictionary)
{
    NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateStr];

    if ([date compare:compareDate] >= 0)
    {
        // download the new file
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. How different is this from what I posted above? Meaning - is it better than what I am currently doing?

Comment: @malaki well, sort of. It compares them via date, rather than via string, which could make some difference.